# Node.js - Reducing Memory of Serialization and Compression of Object in Memory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to serialise and compress a very large object in NodeJS v10 to then upload it to a server, however it runs out of memory sometimes ('Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory')

```
const deflate = util.promisify(zlib.deflate);
const value = await deflate(JSON.stringify(very_large_object), { level: 9 });
```

Is there a way of achieving the same result with a lower memory footprint? Maybe by letting deflate run on a stream so a big string doesn't get created maybe?

*The output format must be identical as I can't change the receiving service.*

Thanks!

Comment: There is a replacement for JSON.stringify that returns a read stream. Look for it.

Comment: How big is the result of `JSON.stringify(very_large_object)`?